# _TtCs21_SwiftDeferredNSArray Error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

When i am trying at add an array of AnyObject to Dictionary in Swift 2.0 it is throughing below error.

_TtCs21_SwiftDeferredNSArray

```
var params = [String:AnyObject]() 
params.updateValue(["HI","Hello"], forKey: "string")  
params.updateValue(["HI","Hello"], forKey: "string") 
print(params)
```

Please let me know how to fix.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post some code. You seem to deal with NSArray.

Comment: var params = [String:AnyObject]()

Comment: var params = [String:AnyObject]()
params.updateValue(["HI","Hello"], forKey: "string")        params.updateValue(["HI","Hello"], forKey: "string")
print(params)

Answer (score 0):

An `Array` is a Value type (`struct`), not an Object. Use `Any` instead of `AnyObject`:

```
// initialize Dictionary which can hold values of type `Any` for keys of type `String` 
var params = [String:Any]()
```

You set an entry like this:

```
// set an entry (value) for key "a string key"
params["a string key"] = ["HI","Hello"]
```

and update it later on:

```
//this...
params.updateValue(["HI","Bye"], forKey: "a string key")
// ... is equivalent to this:
params["a string key"] = ["HI","Bye"]
```